# How do I toggle between Android Dev Guide & Android Resources?

Tags: android

On http://developer.android.com, I often will view the Android reference pages (under the `Resources` tab. I was wondering - is there an easy way to toggle between the `Resources` tab and the `Dev Guide` tab, while staying on the same topic?

To put this into context, I currently have the reference guide open to
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html

But if I select the `Dev Guide`, it opens http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html, which was the last `Dev Guide` page I was looking at.

Comment: I don't think the website supports that.